# Restricting the number of items displayed in CheckedListBox in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, webforms, checkboxlist

I have a checkedlistbox in asp.net web form page as :

```
<asp:CheckBoxList ID="TagListCheckBox" runat="server" Height="100px" Width = "300px" 
style="z-index: 1; left: 63px; top: 146px; position: absolute; TextAlign="Left">
</asp:CheckBoxList>
```

and i add items to it dynamically  :

```
 protected void TagListButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string[] TagList;
        TagList = LhClientClass.client.GetTagList();
        foreach (string s in TagList)
        {
            TagListCheckBox.Items.Add(s);
        }
    }
```

But the height of the list box grows as the number of items being added grows.I want to restrict the number of items to be displayed and add a scroll button to it or something.How do I do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4699625/checkboxlist-scroll-bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to put a div around your control, this should do the trick:

```
<div style="width:200px; height:100px; overflow:auto;">
  <asp:CheckBoxList ID="TagListCheckBox" runat="server" Width="300px" 
  style="z-index: 1; left: 63px; top: 146px; position: absolute; TextAlign="Left">
  </asp:CheckBoxList>
</div>
```